# Check whether a subset with sum divisible by m exists

Tags: dynamic-programming

Given a set of non-negative distinct integers, and a value `m`, determine if there is a subset of the given set with sum divisible by `m`.

The solution on geeksforgeeks states that-

1. If `n > m` there will always be a subset with sum divisible by `m` (which is easy to prove with pigeonhole principle). So we need to handle only cases of `n <= m`.

Can somebody please explain what this case means and what is its relation to pigeonhole principle? Also how is this case different from `n <= m`?

Comment: This is already answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2614458/proving-that-a-set-of-2016-natural-numbers-contain-a-non-empty-set-with-a-sum-di

Comment: I still don't get what they are trying to say. Can you please explain it with respect to my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making this a bit more verbose of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2614458/proving-that-a-set-of-2016-natural-numbers-contain-a-non-empty-set-with-a-sum-di):

Label the numbers `a1, a2, ... an` in any order. Now consider the sums:

```
b1=a1
b2=a1+a2
b3=a1+a2+a3
...
bn=a1+a2+...+an
```

These are either all unique numbers or one of the `a`s are `0` (which is divisible by `m`).

1. Now if any of the `b`s are divisible by `m` we are done.
2. Otherwise:

The remainders of `some non-divisible number/m` can be in the range of `1...(m-1)`. So there are `m-1` numbers of possible remainders`.

Since numbers `b1...bn` weren't divisible by `m` they must have remainders in the range of `1...(m-1)`. So you must pair `n` numbers of `b`s (pigeons) with `m-1` remainders (pigeonholes).

We have more pigeons than pigeonholes => there must be at least two pigeons in the same pigeonhole.

That means: there must be at least two `b`s with the same remainder: call them `bi, bj (i<j)`. Since all of our `b`s are unique and `bi % m == bj % m` (the remainders of `bi/m` and `bj/m` are the same) => `bi - bj = x * m` (where `x` is a positive integer). Therefore `bi - bj` is divisible by `m` and `bi - bj = ai+1 + ... + aj`. Therefore `ai+1 + ... + aj` is divisible by `m` which is exactly what we wanted to proof.

Comment: I edited my answer (accidentally swapped `m` and `n`). Does that make it clear now?

Comment: It is still swapped at few places "Since numbers b1...bn weren't divisible by m they must have remainders in range of 1...(n-1)" I guess you meant to write 1...(m-1)

Answer (score 1):

Let us create a new set of numbers (i.e. `a[ ]` array) by doing prefix sum of given values (i.e. `value[ ]` array).

```
a[0] = value[0]
a[1] = value[0] + value[1]
a[n] = value[0] + value[1] + .... + value[n]
```

Now we have **`n`** new numbers. If any of them are divisible by `m` we are done.


If we divide the `a[ ]` array elements with `m`, we can get remainders in range of `[1, m - 1]`.

But, we have a total of `n` values.

So, there exist two numbers `0<=i,j<=n` in a such that `a[i] mod(m) == a[j] mod(m)`.

Due to the above statement, we can say that `a[i] - a[j] is divisible by m`.


Now, let's consider `i > j`.
We also know that, `a[i] = value[i] + value[i - 1] + ... + value[0]` and `a[j] = value[j] + value[j - 1] + ... + value[0]`.


So, `a[i] - a[j] = value[i] + value[i - 1] + ... + value[i - j + 1]` is also divisible by m.

Comment: In a hurry, welcome to edit my answer to make it more readable, otherwise ill fix it later